# Creating EMR via Lamba Function: Getting Hostname/IP in Config file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, config, emr

I am trying to configure/spin up an EMR via a Lambda function. It works ok, except for getting the IP address or the hostname in the config files. I am trying to configure a property for presto config.properties file which has something like

```
"hive.metastore.uri" : "thrift://<IP address of the Master Node>:9083"
```

I am not sure how to get the IP address or the hostname of the Master node to be replaced in the config file everytime i spin up a new cluster/emr? I tried this -

```
"hive.metastore.uri" : "thrift://${yarn.nodemanager.hostname}:9083"
```

It didn't work, it doesnt replace the hostname with the actual hostname.

```
    Configurations=[
        {
            "Classification": "presto-log",
            "Properties": {
              "com.facebook.presto":"DEBUG",
              "com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory":"DEBUG",
              "com.ning.http.client":"DEBUG",
              "com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager":"DEBUG"
            }
        },
        {
            "Classification": "presto-config",
            "Properties": {
                "http-server.threads.max" : "500",
                "discovery-server.enabled" : "true",
                "sink.max-buffer-size" : "1GB",
                "query.max-memory" : "90GB",
                "query.max-history" : "40",
                "query.min-expire-age" : "100m",
                "http-server.log.path" : "/var/log/presto/http-request.log",
                "http-server.log.max-size" : "67108864B",
                "http-server.log.max-history" : "5",
                "log.max-size" : "268435456B",
                "log.max-history" : "5",
                "distributed-joins-enabled" : "true",
                "query.client.timeout" : "30m"
            }
        },
        {
            "Classification": "presto-connector-hive",
            "Properties": {
                "hive.s3.connect-timeout" : "2m",
                "hive.s3.max-backoff-time" : "10m",
                "hive.s3.max-error-retries" : "50",
                "hive.metastore-refresh-interval" : "1m",
                "hive.s3.max-connections" : "500",
                "hive.s3.max-client-retries" : "50",
                "connector.name" : "hive-hadoop2",
                "hive.s3.socket-timeout" : "2m",
                "hive.metastore.uri" : "thrift://${yarn.nodemanager.hostname}:9083",
                "hive.metastore-cache-ttl" : "20m",
                "hive.s3.staging-directory" : "/mnt/tmp",
                "hive.s3.use-instance-credentials" : "true",
                "hive.external-table-writable " : "true"
            }
        }
    ],
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: What parameter are you trying to set on presto ? If its hive.metastore.uri specifically , EMR will automatically configure this parameter on all nodes to include the fqdn of the master node (where the metastore daemon recides). You do not need to set it manually.

Comment: There are 2 different parameters which i was trying to set. The hive metastore uri is automatically set, Thanks for pointing that out. The other parameter is the presto port in confif.properties. We are using 8081 port instead of 8889. How do i change this? These are the parameters i am trying to change -- discovery.uri=http://ip-<>:8081 and http-server.http.port=8081.

Comment: For  http-server.http.port , you can use presto-config classification with key as 'http-server.http.port'  and '8081' as value. It will simply override the default 8889.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set `hive.metastore.uri` on configurations. EMR will automatically configure this parameter on all nodes to include the FQDN of the master node (where the metastore daemon resides).

If you do want to substitute master/core/task's FQDN on the configurations of applications, there's no supported docs on EMR to do so.   However, Amazon EMR releases are packaged using a system based on [Apache BigTop](http://bigtop.apache.org/). So, you might use parameters defined in yaml files on config API.

https://github.com/apache/bigtop/blob/master/bigtop-deploy/puppet/hieradata/bigtop/cluster.yaml

Example JSON :

```
[
    {
    "Classification": "presto-config",
            "Properties": {
                "http-server.http.port" : "8081",
                "discovery.uri" : "http://%{hiera('bigtop::hadoop_head_node')}:8081",
            }
    }
]
```

Where,

`%{hiera('bigtop::hadoop_head_node')}` : can be used to substitute the master node's FQDN

`%{fqdn}` : can be used to replace its own FQDN.

*Note*: This configuration is not tested to successfully start an EMR cluster and all usage of such custom parameters should be under your own risk.